# mup deploy - Nothing Happens

Tags: meteor, digital-ocean, meteor-up

I'm trying to deploy a meteor app to Digital Ocean. I followed the steps here, https://www.npmjs.com/package/mup and when I run 'mup deploy' from the .deploy directory nothing happens. I included my mup.js file below.

After researching this issue a common solution was to use an absolute path for the pem field but I did that and I also tried a password instead and still nothing happens. Also, if I run 'mup setup', 'mup log', 'mup start', 'mup reconfig', etc. nothing happens. Any ideas?

**.deploy/mup.js**

```
module.exports = {
  servers: {
    one: {
      host: '100.000.00.00',
      username: 'root',
      //password: 'password123' <-- also tried password
      pem: 'C:/Users/User/.ssh/id_rsa'
    }
  },

  meteor: {
    name: 'AppName',
    path: '..',
    servers: {
      one: {}
    },
    buildOptions: {
      debug: true,
    },
    env: {
      ROOT_URL: 'http://100.000.00.00',
      MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://localhost/meteor'
    },
    deployCheckWaitTime: 60
  },

  mongo: {
    oplog: true,
    port: 27017,
    servers: {
      one: {},
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: You could have a look at what's on your server - has it done anything? Are you seeing any kind of errors in your command line? Have you looked at the server error logs?

Comment: I should be able to tail logs from the server using 'mup log -f' but none of my mup commands work for some reason. Nothing happens. Otherwise I'm not sure how to access logs on a Digital Ocean droplet.

Answer (score 2):

So I finally found this same question answered in a couple of places but just in case someone stumbles across this first here is the solution.

Go to the the root directory of the project then run (assuming mup was initialized in the .deploy directory):

```
mup setup --config .deploy/mup.js
mup deploy --config .deploy/mup.js
```

I'm not sure why this isn't in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks. I was also freaking out over the fact nothing happens. This fixed it! :)